# Why is there a red error box with "BS" in my editor in VS Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

[image: screenshot of the "BS" character]

I am a developer of UI in Korea.
I'm using M1 macbook, but sometimes when I type text, I get an error box that says "BS" like capture.

It seems to be an error that doesn't come out even if you google it, so is there a colleague in the world who knows about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a MacOS + MacOS Korean [IME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method) + VS Code bug.

What you're seeing looks like a [unicode control picture character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Pictures). VS Code renders control characters visually by default (the `editor.renderControlCharacters` setting), so either the combination of VS Code and that IME is literally inserting a control picture character, or it is inserting a control character (in which case it is likely the ascii "backspace character" (ascii: 8)) that VS Code is then rendering as a control picture character (U+2408). You can probably find out what character it is by copying from VS Code and pasting it into a tool like https://onlineunicodetools.com/convert-unicode-to-code-points.

An extremely similar issue ticket was opened on VS Code's GitHub repo: [When typing Korean, a red box suddenly appears. #163106](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/163106) but it was closed due to not providing enough detail to reproduce the issue- specifically- what IME needs to be active, and what sequence of keys can be pressed to reproduce it. Since this is most likely a bug, I doubt anyone here can give you any more information than this- at least- given the amount of information that you have provided. I suggest that you find out how *exactly* to reproduce the issue (what IME to use and what keypress sequence to input), and create a new issue ticket on the VS Code GitHub repo providing that information (so that it doesn't suffer the same fate of being closed). If you do, link to the previous issue ticket (`#163106`) in your new issue ticket.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

Comment: It still occurred 2024