# Cannot type single backtick in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Single backtick is working in the browser or anywhere else with the combination Shift + ^ but in VSCode I am unable to type a single backtick, I need to do this combination twice & get 2 backticks and the cursor jumps to the right of the second backtick then when I try to go back with the left arrow key I get a special symbol as in the image; FS in a red square, I think  some other key combination must be in conflict with the backtick. I'm using a Macbook with Swiss keyboard layout.

I tried to assign commands which use Shift + ^ combination to another key combination without ^ but with no success

[image]

Comment: Please, do note that: "_I tried to assign commands which use Shift + ^ combination to another key combination without ^ but with no success_" is a **vague** description 

Comment: Try doing it by pressing space after, this sounds like the typical way accents works, as the backtick could be seen as a backwards é accent (which I honestly dont know how to type). This sounds less like VSCode and more like a keyboard issue.

Comment: @somethinghere this worked, thanks. but I have no issue when typing it in the adress field or anywhere else, for me it has to do with VSCode

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/75103915/11107541, which might be somehow related to your red box thing.

Comment: Maybe vscode has a different language keyboard?